# Dropping "to be" in a sentence?

Tags: verbs

I came across this quote in the novel *Pride and Prejudice*, by Jane Austin:

> She seems a very pleasant young woman.

Was it proper during the time in which the novel was written for people to omit the usage of 'to be'?

Comment: "Woman," singular. And in certain grammatical structures, like your example, yes, it was common to omit the "to be."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not limited to writing of 200 years ago; it is still very common now.

*Be* is such a common verb (it is the most common verb in the English language) that it is often understood, and can be omitted. With impressions of being, especially, *to be* is so obviously part of the phrase that to say/write it seems (*to be*) unnecessary.

> She seems tired = She seems *to be* tired.
>   He appears unwilling to try. = He appears *to be* unwilling to try.

In the Random House Dictionary, the definition of [seems](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/seems) is:

> 1. to appear *to be*, feel, do, etc.
> 2. to appear to one's own senses, judgment, etc.
> 3. to appear *to be true or probable*: It seems likely to rain.
> 4. to appear or pretend *to be such*.

[Synonyms](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=define+seems): appear *(to be)*, have the appearance/air *of being*, give the impression *of being*, look, look as though *one is*, show signs *of being*, look *to be*... etc.

With a deep familiarity with English, one doesn't even notice such an omission.

I'm willing to bet that this occurs in very many languages, if not the majority.